# how can i override the text of datepicker's button in extjs(sencha)?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker

i intend to override the text of datepicker's buttons in extjs(modern) which display as 'cancel' and 'done',i tried both

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    label: 'label',
    name: 'birthday',
    defaultPhonePickerConfig  :{
        doneButton : '确定',
        cancelButton : '取消'
    } 
}
```

and

```
Ext.define("Ext.locale.zh_CN.field.DatePicker", {  
    override: "Ext.field.DatePicker",
    defaultPhonePickerConfig  :{
        doneButton : '确定',
        cancelButton : '取消'
    }
})
```

but they not working,can you tell me what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `picker` config of datepickerfield instead of `defaultPhonePickerConfig`

```
 picker: {
            doneButton: '确定',
            cancelButton: '取消'
        },
```

Comment: many thanks,i handled it by the same way, other side, i handled it with  

`(
listeners :{
        initialize : function(){
            this.setPicker(Ext.create('Ext.picker.Date', {
                cancelButton : '取消',
                doneButton :'确定',
                yearFrom : 1950,
                yearTo : new Date().getFullYear()
            }))
        }
    }
)`

for avoiding some errors maybe cause from sharing a same prototype,what makes me confused is why the docs show we can use 'defaultPhonePickerConfig'